# how to get an element that added after page loaded in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code that add li to ul after page has loaded:

```
 <ul id='hints'></ul>
```

js(jQuery) that adds li to ul after page has loaded:

```
$("#hints").html(<li class='hint'>sometext</li>);
```

jQuery to get `.hint` and change it's style:

```
$(document).on("keypress","#searchText",function (event){
    var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-\uFFFF',
        rtlChars        = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
        rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');
    if(rtlDirCheck.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
        $(".hint").css("textAlign","right");
    } else {            
        $(".hint").css("textAlign","left");
    }
});
```

but `.hint` is not accessible!?

Comment: Does this work if you don't add li with class hints after page load but define it in HTML?

Comment: yes, it works in this situation

Comment: Where is this code  that adds <li> and where is the event handler of serachtext?

Comment: both are in jscript.js file.

Comment: But where? In document.ready event handler or somewhere else?

Comment: in document.ready.

Comment: Try puting the $(document).on("keypress","#searchText" ..   outside document.ready

Comment: I try it outside of document.ready but it does't work

Comment: Can you provide a runnable snippet of your code? It really should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understood your problem but using your code I am able to access HTML content of `$(".hint")`.

By entering something on text box will log HTML content of `li`.
Also by inspecting `<li>` you can see that `style="text-align: left;"` is applied to the `<li>` tag.

```js
$(function() {
  //on load add one element to ul.
  $("#hints").html('<li class="hint">sometext</li>');

  // textbox keypress event
  $(document).on("keypress", "#searchText", function(event) {
    $(".hint").css("color", "red");
    console.log($(".hint").html())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='hints'></ul>

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="search" id="searchText" />
```

Comment: but i cant change its style!?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, just tested, try copy pasting: (Just note you are not adding one more element to list, but setting a single element to list, if you did it again, there wouldn't be two but one)

```js
$(function() {

// textbox keypress event
 $(document).on("keypress","#searchText",function (event){
    var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-\uFFFF',
        rtlChars        = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
        rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');
    if(rtlDirCheck.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){

        $(".hint").css("textAlign","right");

    }else{

        $(".hint").css("textAlign","left");

    }
})
  
  $("#hints").html('<li class="hint">sometext</li>');

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='hints'></ul>

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="search" id="searchText" />
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, i is possible you have a id conflict ie. there is another element with same id in your code. You can search for it to check.

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax  error in your code line

$("#hints").html(sometext);

You have to use "" inside html().

$("#hints").html(**"**sometext**"**);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have changed jscript.js , and it's working properly:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on("keyup","#searchText",function () {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("get", "hint.php?q="+ $(this).val(), true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        $("#hints").show();
        $("#hints").html(this.responseText)
    }
  };
});
 $(document).on("keypress","#searchText",function (event){
    var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-
 \u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-
  \uFFFF',
        rtlChars        = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
        rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');
    if(rtlDirCheck.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
        $(this).css("direction","rtl");
        $("#hints").css("textAlign","right");

    }else{
        $(this).css("direction","ltr");
        $("#hints").css("textAlign","left");
      }
  })
});
```